# how to find upside down of a 2digit number

Tags: java, list

I am trying to write program to find upside down of all double digit number. Actually I have written this code and it works pretty well too.  Any other alternatives to find upside down of an integer. Say 18=81 and 96=69....

```
List < Integer > al = new ArrayList < Integer > ();

al.add(10);al.add(11);al.add(16);al.add(18);al.add(19);al.add(60);al.add(61);
al.add(66);al.add(69);al.add(80);al.add(81);al.add(86);al.add(88);al.add(91);
al.add(96);al.add(98);al.add(99);

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
Integer n = s.nextInt();
if (((String)"" + n).length() == 2) {
    if (al.contains(n))
        System.out.println("yes");
    else
        System.out.println("no");
}
```

Comment: Where is the part where you compare `n` with the "upside down"?

Comment: n is the number I get it from input. I compare n(value at runtime for which upsidedown is calculated) is compared with ArrayList.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Say I entered `18`, yes its length is 2 and yes `al` contains it. So the output is `yes`. Where is the part when `81` is involved? Or is your code still incomplete?

Comment: *Any other alternatives to find upside down of an integer.* yes but first share your attempt.So that we can suggest alternative if there is better way then yours.

Comment: Where is the logic to find upside down of 2 digit number, all this code is doing is to find if a number is present in Arraylist or not

Comment: This program is just about whether a no entered when up side down the number results a proper 2digitnumber. Say if n=23 answer will be no since if i invert 23 it does not results in a proper 2digit number.

Comment: Nitin Dandiyal Thats what I am also asking. Is there any logic to find upside down of a 2 digit number.

Comment: By upside down, you mean reverse of the String that represents the given number?

Comment: What a weird problem.

Comment: @NitinDandriyal, I believe no. LITERALLY upside down like when you flip your screen kind of upside down. HAHA

Comment: wow, its easy then, only 0,1,8,9,6 appear to be proper numbers when they are upside down. You need to check if any other digit is there in the given number

Comment: Nitin Dandriyal. If n=18. upside down n. The resultant number is 81 which is a proper 2 digit number. If i invert 24 the result is not a proper number. How to reverse of a string comes into this place. I am not asking 24=42. i am asking whether 16=91. Can I find 91=16?? any logic???

Comment: Ya Got it. Nitin Dandriyal. Thank youu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple, general algorithm analysing an integer w.r.t. digits with vertical symmetry. (It depends on a certain style of writing digits; note that "continental" '1' is not symmetrical.)

```
private static int[] other = new int[]{0, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 9, -1, 8, 6};
public static int invert( int n ){
    int units = n % 10;
    n /= 10;
    int inv = other[units];
    if( n == 0 ) return inv;
    return inv < 0 ? -1 : invert( n )*10 + inv;
}
```

If a negative value is returned, the number is not symmetrical.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for( int i = 100; i <= 199; ++i ){
        int invi = invert( i );
        if( invi > 0 ){
            System.out.println( i + ": " + invi );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a better way of doing it.
It not only prints yes or no, but also the up side down number

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    al.add("0");
    al.add("1");
    al.add("6");
    al.add("8");
    al.add("9");

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Integer n = s.nextInt();
    String num = n + "";

    if (num.length() == 2) {
        if(al.contains(num.charAt(0) + "") && al.contains(num.charAt(1) + "")) {
            System.out.println("Yes");

            String upSideDownNumber = "";
            if(num.charAt(1) == 6) {
                upSideDownNumber += 9;
            } else if(num.charAt(1) == 9) {
                upSideDownNumber += 6;
            } else {
                upSideDownNumber += num.charAt(1);
            }

            if(num.charAt(0) == 6) {
                upSideDownNumber += 9;
            } else if(num.charAt(0) == 9) {
                upSideDownNumber += 6;
            } else {
                upSideDownNumber += num.charAt(0);
            }

            System.out.println("The up side down number is " + upSideDownNumber);

        } else {
            System.out.println("No");
        }


    } else {
        System.out.println("No");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since only 0,1,6,8,9 look like digits when inverted. You can so below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Set<Integer> upsideDownProperDigits = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(0,1,8,9,6));
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Integer n = s.nextInt();    
    boolean found = true;
    while( n != 0){
        int digit = n % 10;
        if(!upsideDownProperDigits.contains(digit)){
            found = false;
            break;
        }
        n = n/10;
    }
    if(found){
        System.out.println("yes");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("no");
    }
}
```